# Why do i get a problem with freeing arrays?

Tags: arrays, c

so currently we are learning C and we are begining to use pointers .
This program should create a array of a size given then append the a value ( here 5 ) and print the array , then delete all the content and reprint the array .
Everything works fine until the free(tab.data).

Here is the struct used .

```
typedef struct table_t {
  double* data;
  int size
} table_t;
```

and the code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
 #include "TD1.h"

table_t table_new(int n) {
  table_t t;
  t.data = malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
}

void table_printf(table_t tab) {
  int i ;
  for(i=0;i<tab.size;i++){
    printf("%lf \n",tab.data[i]);
  }

}

int table_append(double val, table_t tab){
  int i ;
  for(i=0;i<tab.size;i++){
    tab.data[i]= val ;
  }
}

table_t table_delete(table_t tab)
{
    free(tab.data)  ; //Where the problem is using valgrind
 }


int main()
{
  table_t t ;
  printf(" Enter the size of the array  ");
  scanf("%d ", &t.size  );
  table_new(t.size );
  table_append(5,t);
  table_printf(t);
  table_delete(t);
  table_printf(t);


  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how the `return` statement works in C ? because you have three functions, all of which claim a return value of one specific type or another, and *none* of them actually return *anything*. Ex: `table_new` allocates some memory, stores the pointer to it in a local variable, does not return it (therefore, leaks it), the caller does not reap it, and you then embark on dereferencing an uninitialized member `t.data` from `t` in `main`. And fyi, unrelated, that cannot be your *real* structure definition, as it cannot possibly compile (missing semi-colon).

Comment: Doesn't your compiler give you warnings? If you then enable more warnings, and treat them as errors that must be fixed. Please listen to the compiler and what it tells you.

Comment: Considering that you make the same mistake multiple times, perhaps there's something in your books, tutorials or class that you have missed? Please go back and refresh them. And there's also more problems in your code than the return-value issue. You *really* need to go back to your books or classes.

Comment: You don't actually write to `t.size = n`, so that will be a random value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code:

- `table_new()` causes a memory leak because `t` is a local variable and the memory associated with it is freed after the function returns, as a result the memory you allocated and made `t.data` point to is leaked.
- `table_new()` does not return anything but has return type `table_t`.
- `table_append()` appends a local copy of `tab` not what you pass in. You passed `t` to this function by value in `main()`. This means a local copy of what you passed is made inside `table_append()`. So you aren't changing what was passed instead you are changing a copy which will cease to exist once the function ends.
- `table_append()` returns nothing but has return type `int`.
- `table_delete()` uses `free()` incorrectly. You passed this function a local variable `t` in `main()`. The variable you passed is not a pointer. In order to use it with `free()` it must be a pointer returned from either `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.
- `table_delete()` returns nothing but has return type `table_t`.

Here is a better version:

```
typedef struct table_t { 
        double *data;
        int size;
} table_t;

table_t *table_new(int n)
{   
        table_t *t = malloc(sizeof(table_t));
         
        if (t == NULL) 
            return NULL;

        t->size = n;
        t->data = malloc(sizeof(double) * n);

        if (t->data == NULL) {   
            free(t);
            return NULL;
        }
                
        return t; 
}

void table_printf(table_t *tab)
{    
     for (int i = 0; i < tab->size; i++) {
          printf("%lf \n", tab->data[i]);
     }
}

void table_append(double val, table_t *tab)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tab->size; i++) {
         tab->data[i] = val;
    }
}

void table_delete(table_t *tab)
{
    free(tab->data);
    free(tab);
}


int main()
{
    int table_size;

    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &table_size);
     
    table_t *t = table_new(table_size);

    if (t == NULL)
        return -1;

    table_append(5, t);
    table_printf(t);
    table_delete(t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ow man thank you ... I have to understand all of these bits of code ( Tbh seems toooo hard for me) . Is there any ressource or website I can learn these from ? Like I only find either basic pointer stuff or really advanced .

Comment: https://www.learn-c.org/ is a good resource for beginners. Also practicing these questions https://www.w3resource.com/c-programming-exercises/pointer/index.php should improve your C skills.

Comment: There is no need to allocate every `table_t` on the heap. It is better to let the owner of a  struct choose the apropriate memory storage (stack, global, heap or inline inside another struct). The ability to put structs *not* on the heap is one of the major advantages of languages like c and c++